# Не работает вторая часть кода

Tags: python, telebot

Взял код с ютуба по проверке обязательной подписки на телегу, он прекрасно работает, но вот мой код, который начинается Найти фильм/сериал не работает, хотя без обязательно проверки он работал. Помогите

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('540*************FnGOfL2ypvDQ5c')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    channel_link = "t.me/ki**1*t"
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard = types.KeyboardButton(text="Подтвердить")
    markup.add(keyboard)
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user = message.chat.first_name
    bot.send_message(chat_id, f"Привет,  <b>{user}</b>, чтобы пользоваться ботом, будь добр подписаться\n"
                              f"{channel_link}", reply_markup=markup, parse_mode='html')



@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Подтвердить':
            status = ['creator', 'administrator', 'member']
            for stat in status:
                if stat == bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='@ki****st', user_id=message.from_user.id).status:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Доступ открыт. \n")
                    break



            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Не, не, подпишись я говорю!")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text == "Найти фильм/сериал":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите код: ", parse_mode="html")
    if message.text == "001":
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open('001.jpg', 'rb'))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Код: <b>001</b>\nНазвание: <b>Это все он(2021)</b>", parse_mode="html")
    if message.text == "002":
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open('002.jpg', 'rb'))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Код: <b>002</b>\nНазвание: <b>2+1 (2016)</b>", parse_mode="html")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Код не найден! Проверьте его ниже\n[Вот сюда жмякай](https://t.me/k***8st/)", parse_mode='Markdown')





bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

У тебя 2 одинаковых хендлера, первый ловит сообщения а до 2 они не доходят, второй не нужен, просто передавай message сразу во вторую функцию после проверке в первой

```
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text == "Найти фильм/сериал":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите код: ", parse_mode="html")
    if message.text == "001":
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open('001.jpg', 'rb'))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Код: <b>001</b>\nНазвание: <b>Это все он(2021)</b>", parse_mode="html")
    if message.text == "002":
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open('002.jpg', 'rb'))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Код: <b>002</b>\nНазвание: <b>2+1 (2016)</b>", parse_mode="html")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Код не найден! Проверьте его ниже\n[Вот сюда жмякай](https://t.me/k***8st/)", parse_mode='Markdown')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Подтвердить':
            status = ['creator', 'administrator', 'member']
            for stat in status:
                if stat == bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='@ki****st', user_id=message.from_user.id).status:
                    get_user_text(message)
                else:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Не, не, подпишись я говорю!")
```